# Different result for curl command running locally or on production website

Tags: php, rest, curl

I have a php file that is designed to go through an API for registering users. The first step of this is getting an auth token from the API via a post request. When I run it via my Local (by Flywheel) wordpress site it returns the auth correctly, but when I run the code on a live wordpress server it doesn't work.

Here is the related code. I am quite certain that the agent, secret, and url that I am passing are correct.

```
function getAuth($agent, $secret, $url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $agent . ":" . $secret);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 0'));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl) . '<br/>');
    var_dump(curl_errno($curl) . '<br/>');
    var_dump(curl_error($curl) . '<br/>');
    curl_close($curl);
    $array = json_decode($result, true);
    return $array;
}
```

Perhaps most vexing to me is the error messages I receive from the var dumps. `$array` returns null.

```
string(10) "Array
" string(6) "0
" string(5) "
```

Any light you can shine on this would be very much appreciated!

Edit: Removed the typecast, and it now returns... Things?

array(26) { ["url"]=> string(38) "https://api.ce21.com/token/service/396" ["content_type"]=> string(9) "text/html" ["http_code"]=> int(502) ["header_size"]=> int(140) ["request_size"]=> int(258) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.47892) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.315523) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.351211) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.441982) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(1477) ["speed_download"]=> float(3089) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(1477) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.478869) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(13) "23.96.209.155" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(443) ["local_ip"]=> string(15) "162.241.252.215" ["local_port"]=> int(16238) } int(0) string(0) ""

Edit two: This is the doc for the API I'm working with https://api.ce21.com/interact/index#!/Tokens/Tokens_Post

Comment: echo '<pre>', var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl)), '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', var_dump(curl_errno($curl)), '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', var_dump(curl_error($curl)), '</pre>'; You are typecasting the return value of each function by appending a string to it.

Comment: If you don't have curl library installed in your server it won't work.Most of the shared hosting won't allow you use curl, You can ask your hosting company.It comes builtin in local servers.you can try if curl is working for other type of requests

Comment: @MujnoiGyulaTamas I have removed the typecast, though I'm not sure how to parse the wall of information to make heads or tails of it.

Comment: @Yasir Oh, I didn't realize that was something you need to install. That could be the issue? Would that issue be supported by the edited error message?

Comment: Http_code is saying you got a 502 error bad gateway. Make sure your api is using httpauth for authentication. Maybe you just need to make a simple post with password and username. Api info could help as well

Comment: @MujnoiGyulaTamas I've attached to the docs I'm working with. It seems strange to me that that would be the issue considering that it works when I'm making the same call when running locally.